# vuejs - array variable has value but v-for doesn't iterate

Tags: vue.js

App.vue:

```
<router-view :myFollowings="myFollowings"></router-view>

data() {
    return {
        myFollowings: null,
    }
},
mounted() {
    axios.get('/myFollowings')
        .then(response => {
            this.myFollowings = response.data.myFollowings;
        })
        .catch(error => {
            console.log(error);
        });
    },
```

Home.vue:

```
<myfollowing-modal :myFollowings="myFollowings"></myfollowing-modal>

import MyfollowingModal from './MyfollowingModal.vue';

export default {
    props: ['myFollowings'],
    components: {
        'myfollowing-modal': MyfollowingModal,
    }
}
```

MyfollowingModal.vue:

```
<div class="modal fade" id="myfollowingModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-body">
                <ul class="list-unstyled pr-0 mt-5">
                    <li class="media myfollowing"
                        v-for="(myFollowing, index) in myFollowings"
                        :key="index"
                        :index="index"
                        :myFollowing="myFollowing">
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

export default {
    props: ['myFollowings'],
    mounted() {
        console.log(this.myFollowing); // It returns twice: first time undefined, second time the array fetched from parent of parent(App.vue)
    },
}
```

In MyfollowingModal.vue I want to iterate through the array fetched from its grandparent. But it doesn't go through because the value is undefined. I don't know why but it prints `myFollowings` twice there first time it is undefined so it doesn't start loop but second time has value but it doesn't get that values fetched from parent of parent.

Comment: It would be easier to use VueStash with this kind of structures, but anyway, have you defined `myFollowings ` in `data(){return {myFollowings: []}}` in your App.vue?

Comment: I edited the question. Yes I have that variable declared.

Comment: have you tried doing `response.data` instead of `response.data.myFollowings`?

Comment: I'm sure that it has value. Because when I `console.log` first time it returns undefined but second time it returns the array with the values fetched from `App.vue`. 1. I don't know why it returns its value twice. 2. I don't know why it doesn't iterate through that array.

Comment: myFollowings should be an empty array, not null. It has attached different setters/getters at creation runtime.

Comment: I have set to array either. No result :( BTW when I want to `console.log` in `watch:` it doesn't print any value in `Home.vue` :|

Comment: @kodfire Seems to work okay in [demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/v1qnq6wwm5)